# Cloudflare redirects and CNAME

Tags: redirect, cname-record, cloudflare

Right now I have a domain with CNAME there to another domain.
Is that possbile to make it work like that:
If I go to domain like that mydomain.com it redirects me to the 301 redirect to some custom301domain.com
If I go to mydomain.com/somepage.html it use CNAME and put me to the customCNAMEdomain.com
I think that is not possible, anyway, maybe someone can give some ideas.

Comment: The DNS has no sense of URLs. When you browse `example.com` (please do not use other names for obfuscation) or `example.com/whatever` the DNS query will be the same (for `example.com` `A` and `AAAA` records), it will be up the HTTP server getting the request to handle each differently if this is your wish, as it will not be done at the DNS level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Cloudflare using Page Rules but DNS won't let you do this. All DNS does is translate a hostname to an IP (possibly via one or more CNAMEs) but the DNS server will never even see the */somepage.html* part of the address (and wouldn't know what to do with it if it did).

You'll need to either set this up using Page Rules in Cloudflare, or in your webserver config.